# Problems with OSX OpenGL core profile and building VAO with pre built VBOs

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, opengl

So I've been moving from a legacy profile to Core Profile for the last couple of days.  I'd already moved much of my functionality to use VBOs and shaders, so I thought it wouldn't take that much work.

However, I can't get my new core profile contexts to draw anything at all using glDrawElements.  My application manipulates textures in an app wide background openglContext, the GUI shows various stages of that using OpenGL views that share contexts with the background context.

Each texture object builds it's own VBOs for texture coords and colours as required, leaving me only to provide new vertex VBOs for displaying in views.  The number of vertices and their drawing is standardised so I can share Index buffers.

This is my Pixel format shared between all contexts:

```
+ (NSOpenGLPixelFormat *) defaultPixelFormat
{
    NSOpenGLPixelFormatAttribute attrs[] =
    {
        kCGLPFAOpenGLProfile, kCGLOGLPVersion_3_2_Core,
        NSOpenGLPFADoubleBuffer,
        NSOpenGLPFABackingStore,
        NSOpenGLPFAAllowOfflineRenderers,
        NSOpenGLPFAStencilSize, 8,
        NSOpenGLPFAColorSize, 32,
        NSOpenGLPFADepthSize, 24,
        0
    };
    NSOpenGLPixelFormat* pixFmt = [[NSOpenGLPixelFormat alloc] initWithAttributes:attrs];
    return pixFmt;
}
```

This is a short example of how I setup my VAOs without using a texture, I just want to draw something!

```
- (void) genTestVao
    {
    // Generate buffers first to simulate app environment
    GLfloat verts[] = {
        0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
        100.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
        0.0, 100.0, 0.0, 0.0,
        100.0, 100.0, 0.0, 0.0
    };
    GLfloat colors[] = {
        1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0,
        1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0,
        1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0,
        1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0
    };

    GLushort indices[] = {0, 1, 2, 3};
    if (_testVBuffer) {
        glDeleteBuffers(1, &_testVBuffer);
    }
    if (_testCBuffer) {
        glDeleteBuffers(1, &_testCBuffer);
    }
    if (_testIBuffer) {
        glDeleteBuffers(1, &_testIBuffer);
    }
    glGenBuffers(1, &_testVBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _testVBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(verts), verts, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

    glGenBuffers(1, &_testCBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _testCBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(colors), colors, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    // vert and colors buffers done

    glGenBuffers(1, &_testIBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, _testIBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices), indices, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    // Index buffer done

    // Generate VAO with pre stored buffers
    if (_testVAO) {
        glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &_testVAO);
    }
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &_testVAO);
    glBindVertexArray(_testVAO);
    // Vertex
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _testVBuffer);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(kSCGLVertexAttribPosition);
    glVertexAttribPointer(kSCGLVertexAttribPosition, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(GL_FLOAT) * 4, 0);
    // Colors
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _testCBuffer);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(kSCGLColorAttribPosition);
    glVertexAttribPointer(kSCGLColorAttribPosition, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(GL_FLOAT) * 4, 0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
}
```

Setting up a view matrix:

```
    _mvpMatrix = GLKMatrix4Multiply(
                                    GLKMatrix4MakeOrtho(0.0, self.bounds.size.width, 0.0, self.bounds.size.height, -1.0, 1.0),
                                    GLKMatrix4Identity);
```

The drawing code:

```
    glUseProgram(self.testShader.shaderProgram);
    glUniformMatrix4fv(self.testShader.mvpMatrixLocation, 1, GL_FALSE, self.mvpMatrix.m);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, _testIBuffer);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 4, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE, 0);

    glUseProgram(0);
```

The vertex Shader:

```
#version 150

in vec4 position;
in vec4 color;

uniform mat4 mvpMatrix;

out vec4 vertex_color;

void main()
{
    // perform standard transform on vertex
    gl_Position = position * mvpMatrix;
    vertex_color = color;
}
```

The Fragment Shader:

```
#version 150

in vec4 vertex_color;

out vec4 colourout;

void main()
{
    colourout = vertex_color;
}
```

And finaly the code that links shader and vertices and binds the attribute locations:

```
- (BOOL) createProgramObjectWithVertexShader:(GLuint) vertShader withFragShader:(GLuint) fragShader
{
    _shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(_shaderProgram, vertShader);


    glBindAttribLocation(_shaderProgram, kSCGLVertexAttribPosition, "position");
    GLenum error = glGetError();
    if (error != GL_NO_ERROR) {
        NSLog(@"Error generated getting position!");

        if (error == GL_INVALID_VALUE) {
            NSLog(@"Invalid value");
        } else if (error == GL_INVALID_OPERATION) {
            NSLog(@"Invalid operation");
        } else {
            NSLog(@"unexpected error");
        }
    }
    glBindAttribLocation(_shaderProgram, kSCGLColorAttribPosition,  "color");
    error = glGetError();
    if (error != GL_NO_ERROR) {
        NSLog(@"Error generated getting color!");

        if (error == GL_INVALID_VALUE) {
            NSLog(@"Invalid value");
        } else if (error == GL_INVALID_OPERATION) {
            NSLog(@"Invalid operation");
        } else {
            NSLog(@"unexpected error");
        }
    }

    //glBindAttribLocation(_shaderProgram, kSCGLNormalAttribPosition, "normal");
    //glBindAttribLocation(_shaderProgram, kSCGLTexCoordPosition,     "texcoord");
    error = glGetError();
    if (error != GL_NO_ERROR) {
        NSLog(@"Error generated getting texcoord!");

        if (error == GL_INVALID_VALUE) {
            NSLog(@"Invalid value");
        } else if (error == GL_INVALID_OPERATION) {
            NSLog(@"Invalid operation");
        } else {
            NSLog(@"unexpected error");
        }
    }

    glAttachShader(_shaderProgram, fragShader);

    glLinkProgram(_shaderProgram);

    glDeleteShader(vertShader);
    glDeleteShader(fragShader);
    GLint result = GL_FALSE;
    GLint infoLogLength = 0;

    glGetProgramiv(_shaderProgram, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &infoLogLength);
    if (infoLogLength > 0) {
        char errMsg[infoLogLength];
        glGetProgramInfoLog(_shaderProgram, infoLogLength, &infoLogLength, errMsg);
        NSString *msg = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:errMsg];
        NSLog(@"Self = %@", self);
        NSLog(@"Validate program failed with %@", msg);
        if (![msg hasPrefix:@"WARNING:"]) {
            NSLog(@"Fatal");
            glDeleteProgram(_shaderProgram);
            return NO;
        }

    }
    if (![self getUniformLocations]) {
        NSLog(@"Failed getting uniform variables for %@", self.shaderName);
        glDeleteProgram(_shaderProgram);
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

I'm sure it's something simple, but I just can't see what it is and it's driving me crazy.  The opengl view is setup correctly, if I clear it with colours, it shows correctly, it just won't draw my elements....

Part of the reason I'm moving to core profile is to share code with an iOS app, except for some simple changes, most of my opengl code is es compatible.

EDIT 1:
I created a rough and ready [XCode project that shows the basics on GitHub](https://github.com/seriouscyrus/OSXCoreProfileBasics).  The app delegate holds a base shared openglContext and loads the test shader.  The openGLView is based on a shared context from the App delegate:

EDIT 2:
I updated the project with a couple of corrections, now something draws, but it's not what I expect.  It's a single colour where I've used multiple, and it's in the top right when I expect it to be in the bottom left.

Comment: Unless you use very unusual transformation matrices, the 4th (`w`) coordinate of the vertices should normally be 1.0.

Comment: Thanks, tried that but no effect.  Can i ask what the last coordinate is normally used for?  The only reason i'm using vec4s was because of apple's opengl guidelines for ios

Comment: I tried what you suggested in my demo project, and that did have an effect, just not what I expected.  I'm thinking now my viewport or matrix isn't correct, but not quite sure why...

Answer (score 0):

An apple guy posted the answer to my problems on the apple devforums.

The reason I couldn't get anything to draw was the order of the matrix and position multiplication matters in the vertex shader.  So the line:

```
gl_Position = position * mvpMatrix;
```

Should be:

```
gl_Position = mvpMatrix * position;
```

EDIT: Removed second part of answer as per Reto's comment.

Comment: The second part is false. The enable/disable state set with `glEnableVertexAttribArray()` is part of the VAO state. It can (and typically should, if you want it to be efficient) be set up as part of building the VAO.

Comment: Indeed you're right, I thought I'd tried it but hadn't set them up correctly. will amend the answer.